# how can i display zero values before decimal, from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i have zero values in my MySQL database like 001.9, but when i display them in a combo using php, it only display 1.9. how can i display the full string. i have used datatype as var-char(10).
the code is as below

```
$qry="select i.tableid, i.value_with_zero from table i" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
            //$icdcode = number_format($row[1],2,'.');
            //$icdcode = explode('.', $row[1]);
            $icdcode = strstr($row[1], '.', true);
            echo "<option value=".$row[1].">";`enter code here`
            echo $icdcode."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row[1]."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row[2];
            echo "</option>";
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
```

i tried explode but it doesn't work.

Comment: You could use lpad() in your sql statement.

Comment: actually i have zero values in my database table like 001.9, and i also have values like 9.99, therefore i just want to print them exactly what they are in database.

Comment: Concat empty string ("") to column in select so php will know it should be treated as a string

Comment: 001.9 Cholera, unspecified
002.0 Typhoid fever
002.9 Paratyphoid fever, unspecified
003.0 Salmonella gastroenteritis
003.1 Salmonella septicemia
003.9 Salmonella infection 
These are the database values. I just want to print them only. there is no empty string. and the both values have varchar data type.

Comment: PHP decides what the primitive of a var is when first using it. It may be that the resultvar for i.value_with_zero is converted to say decimal. By adding "" to i.value_with_zero in SQL statement it might convert correctly.

Comment: not working :( why php simply does not show the exact value?

Comment: Then try to_char() instead. If that still doesn't work I am doubting the data in your database to actually contain values like '001.9'

Comment: Worst case you could add char_length to your sql and afterwards concat zeroes based on that length

Comment: data is fully qualified and tested in other databases like access, oracle etc. I used to_char and it is not also displaying the zero values before the decimal. is there a way to show simply 00.01 from database field?

Comment: I am sorry avk bro. hahahahahaha. i found the answer.  u know what i was mistaking! actually i was using a different database connection of same data, and changing on another one. hahahahahahaha. what an misconception. well . thank you very much. I really appreciate your support. :)

Comment: No problem. That's what we're here for :-)